# Match any character except `>` except if preceded by `%`?

Tags: java, regex

What is the fastest way (processing time) to match a string of any characters except if it contains `>`? However, if if that `>` is preceded by `%` (`%>`), it's good.

I want to match  "dhg87y93..r,y9w", "dhkajdah%>daadas%>" , "adsdsa %> /r/n **(line break)** %>", or even "" but not "adhajs>dadsadas".

I tried `([^>]*(%>)?[^>]*)*` but it takes too much processing power to even work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `^([^%>]|%>?)*$`. The part before the `|` matches everything but `%` and `>`. The second part matches `%` and then allows `>` after it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it will. The `%>?` part matches both `%` and `%>`.

Comment: I believe this answer is "fastest way", since it doesn't require any backtracking, though you should make the group non-capturing. And if used with `matches()`, the `^` and `$` anchors are redundant.

Comment: @Andreas: On regex101 this regex takes 187 steps, John's rages takes 203 steps and my regex takes 132 steps.

Comment: @anubhava It takes that number of steps to parse, which doesn't necessarily mean it's the fastest way of matching any string.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs: I have further updated my regex that takes only 85 steps now. Less steps means faster execution of regex. These are not just parsing steps.

Comment: @anubhava Splendid. I've added an answer to compare the provided answers. The numbers tell the tale. Leo's answer is certainly not the fastest. I suspect having newlines in the input string will give some edge to John's compared to yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^>]*(?:%>[^>]*)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUP6yN/3)

**Java Code:**

```
// anchors are implicit in String.matches(regex)

boolean isMatch = str.matches("[^>]*(?:%>[^>]*)*");
```

Total number of steps taken to complete: **85**

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^                # start (Implicit in matches())
[^>]*            # match zero or more of any character except >
(?:              # start of non-capture group
   %>            # match %> 
   |             # OR
   [^>]*         # match zero or more of any character except >
)*               # end of non-capture group. Match zero or more of this group
$                # end (Implicit in matches())
```

Comment: Getting rid of the non-capturing makes it even faster. In all testcases.

Comment: non-capturing are meant for saving unnecessary memory being spent in capturing groups.

Comment: I know what it's for. OP asks for fastest, not cheapest.

Comment: When you have very large strings to parse then consuming memory also slows down execution.

Comment: There we go again: although everything you say is true, my point is you don't give any numbers nor do you measure. And whenever you come up with numbers (nr of steps) they're not explaining the (in some cases, lack of) speed.

Comment: **in some cases** is the keyword here. Any kind of benchmarking you do will vary significantly with kind of input it needs to match.

Answer (score 2):

Pretend that `%>` is a single character:

```
([^>]|%>)*
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added this answer to caution people trusting answers like "this is the fastest regex...". And again, no, the number of steps that sites like regex101 provide is an indication, but not an absolute number that will guarantee the speed of matching with a specific regex. I've put together a scratch file that uses all examples in the question, and all regex answers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class scratch_5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("dhg87y93..r,y9w");
            add("dhkajdah%>daadas%>");
            add("adsdsa %>/r/n%>");
            add("but not \"adhajs>dadsadas");
        }};
        List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("([^%>]|%>?)*");      // Leo Aso
            add("[^>]*(?:%>[^>]*)*"); // anubhava
            add("([^>]|%>)*");        // John Kugelman
        }};

        int i = 0;
        for (String test : tests) {
            System.out.println("string " + test);
            System.out.println(new String(new char[test.length() + 7]).replace("\0", "="));
            for (String pattern : patterns) {
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                boolean res = test.matches(pattern);
                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                long duration = (endTime - startTime);
                System.out.format("with pattern %d: %s with duration %TQ\n", (i++ % 3) + 1, res, duration);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Running this gives:

```
string dhg87y93..r,y9w
======================
with pattern 1: true with duration 584676
with pattern 2: true with duration 45438
with pattern 3: true with duration 36220

string dhkajdah%>daadas%>
=========================
with pattern 1: true with duration 56894
with pattern 2: true with duration 59195
with pattern 3: true with duration 73102

string adsdsa %>/r/n%>
======================
with pattern 1: true with duration 63597
with pattern 2: true with duration 49039
with pattern 3: true with duration 34486

string but not "adhajs>dadsadas
===============================
with pattern 1: false with duration 58285
with pattern 2: false with duration 39279
with pattern 3: false with duration 42053
```

We need to ignore the length first result of the first test, which is due to initialization. We can conclude that - on average - the second regex is the fastest, but that it's not always the case. It shows that it depends on the string you're matching against which one will be faster. So, the correct answer to the question would be: **it depends**.

To be absolute sure of the speed of parsing a specific string using a regex compared to others, you should know the strategy that the parser is using.

**Addendum 1**: if you compile the pattern, even different results appear.

```
    Matcher matcher;
    Pattern cp;
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println("string " + test);
        System.out.println(new String(new char[test.length() + 7]).replace("\0", "="));
        for (String pattern : patterns) {
            cp = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            matcher = cp.matcher(test);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = (endTime - startTime);
            System.out.format("with pattern %d: %s with duration %TQ\n", (i++ % 3) + 1, matcher.find(), duration);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Results are:

```
string dhg87y93..r,y9w
======================
with pattern 1: true with duration 39342
with pattern 2: true with duration 2296
with pattern 3: true with duration 1520

string dhkajdah%>daadas%>
=========================
with pattern 1: true with duration 2365
with pattern 2: true with duration 2428
with pattern 3: true with duration 2452

string adsdsa %>/r/n%>
======================
with pattern 1: true with duration 2449
with pattern 2: true with duration 2147
with pattern 3: true with duration 1505

string but not "adhajs>dadsadas
===============================
with pattern 1: true with duration 1663
with pattern 2: true with duration 1569
with pattern 3: true with duration 2003
```

One thing is clear: if you need to speed up things, compile your patterns. Which is like preaching to the choir, I guess. ;-)

Comment: or even "" (empty string), but not "adhajs>dadsadas" :D